# I can't install discord components

Tags: discord.py

I want to install discord components, but I'm still getting this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord_components (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord_components
> I tried every single command, here is list:
> **pip install --upgrade discord-components**
> **pip install discord.components**
> **py -m pip install --upgrade discord-components**
> And I tried on this versions of python:
> **3.19.13
> 3.7.9
> 3.11.3
> 3.10.3**

Someone help me with instalation of it.

Comment: discord-components has been archived for a while now, since discord.py has all of the features of discord-components built-in for about a year now, starting with version 2.0. As you don't need discord-components anymore it seems like the package has been removed from pip. If you are following a guide or something similar that tells you to install this, you might want to look somewhere else as it is clearly outdated.